# Wordpress add extra tags to my HTML in page

Tags: html, wordpress

I try to add this HTML inside a Wordpress page in Text tab:

```
<div class="homepage-section-row" style="margin-top:5px">
<a href="#">
    <p>Test</p>
    <span class="icon-comment-alt fblock-icon"></span>
</a>
```

But when I see the page source, I see some extra tags:

```
<div class="homepage-section-row" style="margin-top:5px">
<a href="#"><p></p>
<p>Test</p>
</a><p><a href="#">        <span class="icon-comment-alt fblock-icon"></span><br>
</a>
</p></div>
```

I'm using Wordpress 4.1. What should I do?

Comment: It appears that Wordpress is trying to be smart and convert your line breaks into HTML line breaks...

Comment: @jsve Yes! but I don't know why it is doing it in Text mode! there should be plain HTML. do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop). I also find it incredibly annoying, but when you have a website with a lot of writers, it is very useful.

Here is a plugin I have used to turn it off - [HTML Markup Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup-plus/)

Comment: That's it! You can not imagine what a big favor you did to me :)

Answer (score 2):

In Wordpress text editor, any block level like `<div>` `<p>` `<ul>` elements will be reserved, any inline elements like `<a>` `<span>` will be automatically wrapped in to `<p>` tags if there are line breaks surrounded.

What you could do is make everything one line:

```
<div class="homepage-section-row" style="margin-top:5px"><a href="#"><p>Test</p><span class="icon-comment-alt fblock-icon"></span></a></div>
```

OR this is also acceptable:

```
<div class="homepage-section-row" style="margin-top:5px">
<a href="#"><span>Test</span><span class="icon-comment-alt fblock-icon"</span></a>
</div>
```

OR update the html tags if you want to have multiple items:

```
<ul class="homepage-section-row">
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: But it's not a good idea! I think it's like a bug! It's so hard to edit my HTML code after doing this way. is there any better solution?

Comment: I believe It is not a bug. You might be able to find and use a plugin to change the behavior. Also updated my answer.

Comment: So what if I want to have multiple <a> tag and want to show them besides each others? It's not a good option to write all of them in one line! Is there any solution for this?